# Why is my Netty based TCP server hanging up with 100% CPU usage?

Tags: centos, nio, netty, java

I've developed a Netty based TCP server to receive maintain connection with GSM/GPRS based devices and to persist those data in MySql database. Currently 5K connections are handled. Devices send periodic messages with interval of 30-60 secs, but connections are kept alive to maintain duplex communication.

The server application consumes 1-2% CPU in normal operation with peaks up to 10%, average load is very low. However after 6 hours to 48 hours normal operation, server application hangs up with constant 100% CPU consumption, thread dump indicates that epoll selector is the reason for high CPU usage. Applications still keeps connections for a few hours, then CPU consumption increases to 200% and most of the connections are released.

In the beginning of the project we used MINA and had the same issue with 1K active connections, that is why we switched to Netty. Until 5K connections Netty was much more stable and hang up period was 1-2 weeks.

**Our server configuration:**

- I7-2600 Quad Core CPU,
- 8 GB Ram, Centos 5.0,
- Open JDK 6.0,
- Netty 3.2.4 (Netty is updated to 3.5.2 a few hours ago)

In order to overcome this problem we will update `JDK` to 7.0 (`JDK` has a new I/O implementation optimized for asynchronous operations) and try different OS including FreeBSD, Windows Server since each operating system has different strategies for handling I/O.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks..

Comment: I think without a copy of the code no one would be able to pinpoint the error.

Comment: I would try to upgrade java version first.. When using nio its important to have a recent java version. Not sure what version of openjdk 6 you use..

Comment: Thanks Norman, I use OpenJDK "1.6.0_20", I will update OpenJDK and share my experience.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the Epoll bug.

The app is proxying connections to backend systems. The proxy has a pool of channels that it can use to send requests to the backend systems. If the pool is low on channels, new channels are spawned and put into the pool so that requests sent to the proxy can be serviced. The pools get populated on app startup, so that is why it doesn't take long at all for the CPU to spike through the roof (22 seconds into the app lifecycle). [Source](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/327)

Netty has a workaround built-in. Not sure from which version though, will have to update later.

```
System.setProperty("org.jboss.netty.epollBugWorkaround", "true");
```

Comment: In my similar case, after ~24 hours the netty epoll thread consumes ~50% CPU (on an otherwise basically idling server). Setting the `epollBugWorkaround` property doesn't seem to have any effect. Java is Amazon Correto 11, Netty is 4.1.19

Comment: Update: It looks like, contrary to what the Netty 4.0.0 release notes will have you think, as of Netty 4.0.0 the workaround is fully integrated and enabled by default - but with a very high threshold - not 10 as mentioned in the bug report linked in the answer, but 512. To enable the original workaround behavior, set the system property `io.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold` to the threshold that you would like.